# Glassfish - get all queues in a session

Tags: java, glassfish

My question is pretty simple, but I am having a bad time finding a solution.
I want to be able to get all the queues in the server (or session, that would also be ok). Is that possible?

My situation is the following:
I am new to openMQ, Glassfish, activeMQ and so on. I developed a monitoring system for activeMQ in which I get all the existing queues and show to the user, so it can get information about number of messages and so on.
To do that, I have this code:

```
ActiveMQConnection.makeConnection("tcp://localhost:61616");
activeMQConnection.start();

//Get queues
DestinationSource destinationSource = activeMQConnection.getDestinationSource();
Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = destinationSource.getQueues();
```

this last line gets all the queues for the connection, and this is exactly what I need. But this was my code for ActiveMQ.

Now the team decided to change to openMQ, and I have to adapt my monitoring system to be able to handle that. I would like to use LDAP so I can do it technology-independent. After a lot of research I came to this code:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("cn=QueueConnectionFactory");
```

Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
  Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Queue myQueue = session.createQueue("myQueue");

This is good, because it would be completely independente (I think, have to test it). But the problem is that I have to register the queue, something I would not like to do. I would like to get all the existing queues in the server without any need for registering, but I can't find any GetQueues() method or any way to mimic its behavior.

I also found out the the DestinationSource class in activeMQ inherits from MessageListener, but this class doesn't provides any similar method :(

Could you please help me?

thank you,
Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do that using JMX, here is the code:

```
HashMap environment = new HashMap();
  String[] credentials = new String[] { "user", "pass" };
  environment.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, credentials);

  JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("URL");

  // Get JMX connector, supplying user name and password
  JMXConnector jmxc1 = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, environment);

  // Get MBean server connection
  MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc1.getMBeanServerConnection();

  ObjectName destMgrConfigName = new ObjectName(MQObjectName.DESTINATION_MANAGER_MONITOR_MBEAN_NAME);

  // Create operation's parameter and signature arrays

  Object opParams[] = {};

  String opSig[] = {};

  // Invoke operation
  ObjectName[] objectNames = (ObjectName[]) mbsc.invoke(destMgrConfigName, DestinationOperations.GET_DESTINATIONS, opParams, opSig);

  for (ObjectName objectName : objectNames) {
   System.out.println(objectName.getCanonicalName());
   System.out.println(objectName.getKeyProperty("name"));
  }
```

more references here: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2129291&tstart=0